# How to custom preview mode in Sanity Studio with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, sanity

I have problem to show the preview mode because the url must contain few parameter that is "category" and "slug". (example in my picture bellow).

[This is the error url with undefined param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uylUc.png)

So, i cant get the param for my URL

This is my code

```
// structure.ts

interface Doc extends SanityDocument {
  slug: { current: any };
  categories: {
    title: string;
    description: string;
  };
}

function getPreviewUrl(doc: Doc) {
  return doc?.slug?.current
    ? `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL || window.location.host}/articles/${
        doc.categories.title
      }/${doc.slug.current}`
    : `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL || window.location.host}`;
}

export const defaultDocumentNode = (
  S,
  { schemaType },
) => {
  switch (schemaType) {
    case `article`:
      return 
        S.view
          .component(Iframe)
          .options({
            url: (doc: Doc) => getPreviewUrl(doc)
          })
      ]);

    default:
      return S.document().views([S.view.form()]);
  }
};
```

in my code above, i have implement custom component for preview mode using Iframe, and set the option to getPreviewUrl, but the doc value in this code 'url: (doc: Doc) => getPreviewUrl(doc)', just return default schema structure data that contain reference especially for the categories data. so in this case i want to get data from category schema by reference from my article schema, so i can use the data in **getPreviewUrl** function.

This is for the article schema

```
{
  "author": {
    "_ref": "31c9cd97-6fc3-45d2-a13b-d0dbfa3e4681",
    "_type": "reference"
},
"categories": [
    {
        "_key": "111749138b41",
        "_ref": "581dfb13-ab8c-4da9-8a29-1e052f6ceb76",
        "_type": "reference"
    }
],
"description": "This is the first ever article on my platform!",
"slug": {
    "_type": "slug",
    "current": "my-first-article"
},
"title": "My First Article"
```

}

this is my category schema structure data

`category : [ { _id : string, title : string } ]`

How i can get data from category schema by reference from my article schema ?, i have read the documentation on sanity.io, but still didn't get it.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: in this case i want to make the structure of my doc to be
"categories": [
    {
        title : string
    }]
i need to use categories[0].title for my params to match the url that i have. but doc just return reference of category like the following
"categories": [
    {
        "_key": "111749138b41",
        "_ref": "581dfb13-ab8c-4da9-8a29-1e052f6ceb76",
        "_type": "reference"
    }
]
because the structure url that i have is host/articles/[category]/[slug]
so i need to know the category

Answer (score 1):

I **have solved** my problem by change my code such the following

```js
import Iframe from 'sanity-plugin-iframe-pane';
import { DefaultDocumentNodeResolver } from 'sanity/desk';
import { SanityDocument } from 'sanity';
import { client } from './lib/sanity.client';

interface Doc extends SanityDocument {
  slug: { current: any };
}

async function getPreviewUrl(doc: Doc) {
  const query = `*[_type == 'article' && _id == $id] {
     categories[0] -> {
       title
     }
 }`;
  const [{ categories }] = await client.fetch(query, { id: doc._id });
  return doc?.slug?.current && categories
    ? `${
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL ||
        window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host
      }/articles/${categories?.title}/${doc.slug.current}`
    : `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL || window.location.host}`;
}

export const defaultDocumentNode: DefaultDocumentNodeResolver = (
  S,
  { schemaType },
) => {
  switch (schemaType) {
    case `article`:
      return S.document().views([
        S.view.form(),
        S.view
          .component(Iframe)
          .options({
            url: (doc: Doc) => getPreviewUrl(doc),
            defaultSize: 'desktop',
            reload: { button: true },
            attributes: {},
          })

          .title('Preview'),
      ]);

    default:
      return S.document().views([S.view.form()]);
  }
};
```

maybe any other better solution for my case?